# Trying to install Boot Camp Drivers on MacBook2,1 for Windows XP

Tags: bootcamp

I am trying to install Boot Camp Drivers for windows XP on a Late 2006 MacBook (MacBook2,1) but i cannot find any drivers for it. Could you help me find some?

Answer (score 1):

The Boot Camp drivers for (really) old iMacs is included on the OS X Snow Leopard installation DVD. [This DVD can still be purchased from Apple](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MC573Z/A/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard). Since Snow Leopard was [released in 2009](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Snow_Leopard), the DVD should contain the XP drives for your 2006 Mac.

Since OS X Leopard was released on DVD in [late 2007](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Leopard), the Boot Camp drivers on this DVD should also work with a XP installation on your Mac.

Apple does have a [Boot Camp - Windows XP Drivers Update 2.1](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL830?viewlocale=en_CA&locale=en_CA) website which states the following:

> Note: This download contains complete copies of Boot Camp Windows XP Drivers (version 2.1).  If you have Boot Camp drivers already installed, it will update them.  **If you do not have any Boot Camp drivers installed, it will install version 2.1 drivers onto your already installed Windows OS**.

Since the Post Date is Apr 24, 2008 and the website mentions OS X Leopard, I would assume the download would contain the drivers for all 2006 Macs that can run Windows XP. The web site has a special note, which is repeated below.

> Important: Installation of Boot Camp 2.1 is required before installing Windows XP Service Pack 3 (SP3)

There is also a [Boot Camp Drivers Update 2.2 for Windows](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL967?viewlocale=en_CA&locale=en_CA). However, this does not appear to contain all the XP drivers. Therefore, this update should be applied after installing Boot Camp 2.1.